How to properly map user input to generic types in Rust?
I'm trying to write a Cheat Engine in Rust, following the guide in https://lonami.dev/blog/woce-1/. The code in the blog does not provide a friendly interface so I decide to write one of my own. The interface proves difficult to implement. Concretely, I found it hard to bridge user input string and the underlined generic type. A brief overview of the problem would look like this:
I got a type Foo<T:Sized> where T is one of the basic types u32,u64,f32,f64. T must be sized since I need to parse it as raw bytes. Now if I instantiate Foo like Foo<u32> everything works smoothly. But consider this struct as a global state:
struct State{
    count:uint,
    foo: Option<Foo<T>>,
}

Of course the code won't compile since T is unbounded and cannot be known at compile time. Neither can I have the State be generic since I don't know what T is when it is constructed. T is determined by a user input string like "u64" or "u32".
My first attempt is to use a trait object, something like
struct State{
    count:uint,
    foo: Option<Foo<Box<dyn Sized>>>,
}

This does not work, the first rule of a trait object is the trait must not be Sized.
Next I try to bind Foo instead, writing something like:
impl Bar<T> for Foo<T>{}
struct State{
    count:uint,
    foo: Option<Box<dyn Bar<T>>>,
}

It does not help, still I don't know what to do with this T.
Now my workaround is to wrap the generic type in an enum, to have an enum like:
enum FooEnum{
    u64(Foo<u64>),
    u32(Foo<u32>),
}

and match the enum when handling it. It works, but it is quite unpretty, especially when there are several other types must be enumized like Foo. I'm now using macros to make it less tedious to code, but it is still a pain to enum every possible type whenever such a type is accessed.
I checked the crate enum_dispatch, putting the Bar trait into a enum_dispatch macro yields "Unsupported trait item" error with no further information.
My question is, providing I have the knowledge of what T could possibly be a priori, could such a type be handled less painfully?
Update: It seems I didn't read enough of the guide. There's one solution to the problem later in the texts, by removing the Sized trait requirement and make it a trait object. Nevertheless the original problem is still interesting, about how to properly handle a sized trait with user input.

Just make Foo an enum.

Better, make T an enum. There's only a bounded number of types you can have as state.

To make T an enum is viable, in fact I wrote the first version using enum and refactor it to be generic typed, in consideration of memory usage. To support both u8 and u64 in a single enum easily cause a 8 times overhead for u8.

Are you just guessing that it's important to save these few bytes, or has that been determined through careful benchmarking/profiling/analysis?  There's more than a small chance that it will make negligible to zero difference (e.g. because of machine word size, or alignment and padding of containing structs etc - which could eliminate differences, or possibly even lead to performance degradation).  Remember Knuth's maxim: "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

The comment by @eggyal is fair. Add a benchmark here. The benchmark is done by running two scans with two enums, one with only one variant containing a u8, the other one has two variants u8 and u64. The result shows that the build with u8 and u64 enum consume around 50% more memory. Which is actually less than my expectation. Apologize for my groundless statement.

To answer your quesetion about generics: No, you don't want to use generics unless you can use a single trait to cover all possible use cases of that generic type used all over your code (and this is very contagious!)

One more point: Box<dyn Trait> will likely use more memory than an enum, because it has to allocate each item and store a pointer to each item.
